# Cn1 AutoSizeMode = true, hides text

Tags: codenameone

Whenever I enable the autosize mode on my components, the label text dissapears

```
    final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.setText(text);
    //checkBox.setAutoSizeMode(true);
    m_content.add(m_textModeLayout.createConstraint(), checkBox);

    final PickerComponent pickerComponent = PickerComponent.createStrings(opciones);
    final Label labelForComponent = pickerComponent.getEditor().getLabelForComponent();
    labelForComponent.setText(text);
    //labelForComponent.setAutoSizeMode(true);
    pickerComponent.onTopMode(true);

    final TextComponent textComponent = new TextComponent();
    final Label labelForComponent = textComponent.getEditor().getLabelForComponent();
    textComponent.labelAndHint(text);
    labelForComponent.setText(text);
    //labelForComponent.setAutoSizeMode(true);
    textComponent.onTopMode(true);
```

The problem I´m facing is that some of the texts are really big and I need a way for those to be displayed.

Thanks!

Comment: In case you wonder, here is my form init...  m_textModeLayout = new TextModeLayout(8, 1);
        m_content = new Container();
        m_content.setLayout(m_textModeLayout);
        m_content.setScrollableY(true);
        m_content.add(m_textModeLayout.createConstraint(), new SpanLabel("Instruction"));
        add(CENTER, m_content);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autosize mode won't work here due to the unique layout constraint which prevents us from knowing the available size beforehand. It will only work in a deterministic layout.

I would suggest rethinking your design and using a `SpanLabel` below the text component to represent the additional details. That way the text won't shrink "too much".

An alternative would be setting the label size of the text to a specific smaller size but that might make the text unreadable to some users and make things worse as a result.

Comment: As always, thank you for your help. Is changing the layout a possibility?

Comment: Spanlabel did the trick... I guess this TextComponent and PickerComponent classes are designed with only short texts in mind. Thank you so much!